# Fatal error of usb debuging opencv app

Tags: android, opencv, sony-xperia

My `open CV` application makes error when i debug via `USB`. it stops the immediately. Even Opencv face detection example is not working which given by the `OPENCV`. I used the latest `OPENCV manager 2.4.9.0rev 1`. 
app works perfectly on other mobiles and my one is `sony M2`

```
11-20 22:54:43.473: I/Main(31635): called onCreate
11-20 22:54:43.483: D/CameraBridge(31635): Attr count: 5
11-20 22:54:43.493: W/ContextImpl(31635): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=org.opencv.engine.BIND } android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService:524 org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper.initOpenCV:24 org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader.initAsync:79 
11-20 22:54:43.503: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635): Service connection created
11-20 22:54:43.513: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635): Trying to get library path
11-20 22:54:43.583: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635): Trying to get library list
11-20 22:54:43.643: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635): Library list: ""
11-20 22:54:43.643: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635): First attempt to load libs
11-20 22:54:43.643: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635): Trying to init OpenCV libs
11-20 22:54:43.643: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635): Trying to load library /data/app-lib/org.opencv.engine-1/libopencv_java.so
11-20 22:54:43.643: D/dalvikvm(31635): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/org.opencv.engine-1/libopencv_java.so 0x419c4d68
11-20 22:54:43.673: D/dalvikvm(31635): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.opencv.engine-1/libopencv_java.so 0x419c4d68
11-20 22:54:43.673: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635): OpenCV libs init was ok!
11-20 22:54:43.673: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635): First attempt to load libs is OK
11-20 22:54:43.673: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635): General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.9 =====================================
11-20 22:54:43.673: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   Version control:               2.4.9
11-20 22:54:43.673: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   Platform:
11-20 22:54:43.673: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Host:                        Linux 3.2.0-56-generic x86_64
11-20 22:54:43.673: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Target:                      Linux 1 armv7-a
11-20 22:54:43.673: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     CMake:                       2.8.12.1
11-20 22:54:43.673: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     CMake generator:             Ninja
11-20 22:54:43.673: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     CMake build tool:            /usr/local/bin/ninja
11-20 22:54:43.673: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Configuration:               Release
11-20 22:54:43.673: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   C/C++:
11-20 22:54:43.673: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
11-20 22:54:43.673: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     C++ Compiler:                /opt/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++  (ver 4.6)
11-20 22:54:43.673: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     C++ flags (Release):         -fexceptions -frtti -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -fpic -funwind-tables -finline-limit=64 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack  -fweb -fwrapv -frename-registers -fsched2-use-superblocks -fsched2-use-traces -fsched-stalled-insns-dep=100 -fsched-stalled-insns=2 -fno-tree-vectorize   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpu=neon -mthumb -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
11-20 22:54:43.673: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     C++ flags (Debug):           -fexceptions -frtti -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -fpic -funwind-tables -finline-limit=64 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack  -fweb -fwrapv -frename-registers -fsched2-use-superblocks -fsched2-use-traces -fsched-stalled-insns-dep=100 -fsched-stalled-insns=2 -fno-tree-vectorize   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpu=neon -marm -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O0 -g -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
11-20 22:54:43.673: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     C Compiler:                  /opt/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     C flags (Release):           -fexceptions -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -fpic -funwind-tables -finline-limit=64 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack  -fweb -fwrapv -frename-registers -fsched2-use-superblocks -fsched2-use-traces -fsched-stalled-insns-dep=100 -fsched-stalled-insns=2 -fno-tree-vectorize   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpu=neon -mthumb -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     C flags (Debug):             -fexceptions -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -fpic -funwind-tables -finline-limit=64 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack  -fweb -fwrapv -frename-registers -fsched2-use-superblocks -fsched2-use-traces -fsched-stalled-insns-dep=100 -fsched-stalled-insns=2 -fno-tree-vectorize   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpu=neon -marm -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O0 -g -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now 
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now 
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Precompiled headers:         NO
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   OpenCV modules:
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     To be built:                 core androidcamera flann imgproc highgui features2d calib3d ml objdetect video contrib photo java dynamicuda legacy gpu ocl stitching superres ts videostab
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Disabled:                    world
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Disabled by dependency:      -
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Unavailable:                 nonfree python viz facedetect imuvstab tegra vstab
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   Android: 
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Android ABI:                 armeabi-v7a with NEON
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     STL type:                    gnustl_static
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Native API level:            android-9
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     SDK target:                  android-11
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Android NDK:                 /opt/android-ndk-r8c (toolchain: arm-linux-androideabi-4.6)
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     android tool:                /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android (Android SDK Tools, revision 22.6.)
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Google Play package:         YES
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Android examples:            YES
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   GUI: 
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     GTK+ 2.x:                    NO
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     GThread :                    NO
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     GtkGlExt:                    NO
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     OpenGL support:              NO
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     VTK support:                 NO
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   Media I/O: 
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     ZLib:                        z (ver 1.2.3)
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     JPEG:                        build (ver 62)
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     PNG:                         build (ver 1.5.12)
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   Video I/O:
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     AndroidNativeCamera:         YES, use prebuilt libraries
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   Other third-party libraries:
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Use IPP:                     NO
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.1.2)
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Use TBB:                     YES (ver 4.1 interface 6102)
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Use OpenMP:                  NO
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Use GCD                      NO
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Use Concurrency              NO
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Use C=:                      NO
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Use Cuda:                    YES (ver 6.0)
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Use OpenCL:                  YES
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   NVIDIA CUDA
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Use CUFFT:                   YES
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Use CUBLAS:                  NO
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     USE NVCUVID:                 NO
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     NVIDIA GPU arch:             32
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     NVIDIA PTX archs:
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Use fast math:               NO
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   OpenCL:
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Version:                     dynamic
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Include path:                /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Use AMD FFT:                 NO
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Use AMD BLAS:                NO
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   Python:
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2 (ver 2.7.3)
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   Java:
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.8.2)
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Java tests:                  YES
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   Documentation:
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Build Documentation:         YES
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Sphinx:                      /usr/local/bin/sphinx-build (ver 1.1.3)
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     PdfLaTeX compiler:           /usr/bin/pdflatex
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   Tests and samples:
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Tests:                       YES
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     Performance tests:           YES
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):     C/C++ Examples:              NO
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   Install path:                  /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/build/builds/o4t/install
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/build/builds/o4t
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635): -----------------------------------------------------------------
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635): General configuration for OpenCV4Tegra =====================================
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   inner version                  2.4.9
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   memory allocator               YES
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   hardware link                  YES
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   compact sources                YES
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635):   logging enabled                NO
11-20 22:54:43.683: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635): -----------------------------------------------------------------
11-20 22:54:43.683: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635): Init finished with status 0
11-20 22:54:43.683: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635): Unbind from service
11-20 22:54:43.693: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(31635): Calling using callback
11-20 22:54:43.693: I/Main(31635): OpenCV loaded successfully
11-20 22:54:43.703: I/Adreno-EGL(31635): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.044_msm8226_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.044__release_AU ()
11-20 22:54:43.703: I/Adreno-EGL(31635): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.15
11-20 22:54:43.703: I/Adreno-EGL(31635): Build Date: 05/16/14 Fri
11-20 22:54:43.703: I/Adreno-EGL(31635): Local Branch: 
11-20 22:54:43.703: I/Adreno-EGL(31635): Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.044
11-20 22:54:43.703: I/Adreno-EGL(31635): Local Patches: NONE
11-20 22:54:43.703: I/Adreno-EGL(31635): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
11-20 22:54:43.753: D/OpenGLRenderer(31635): Enabling debug mode 0
11-20 22:54:43.763: D/CameraBridge(31635): call surfaceChanged event
11-20 22:54:43.763: D/OpenCV::camera(31635): CvCapture_Android::CvCapture_Android(0)
11-20 22:54:43.763: D/OpenCV::camera(31635): Library name: libopencv_java.so
11-20 22:54:43.763: D/OpenCV::camera(31635): Library base address: 0x5f976000
11-20 22:54:43.793: D/OpenCV::camera(31635): Libraries folder found: /data/app-lib/org.opencv.engine-1/
11-20 22:54:43.793: D/OpenCV::camera(31635): CameraWrapperConnector::connectToLib: folderPath=/data/app-lib/org.opencv.engine-1/
11-20 22:54:43.793: E/OpenCV::camera(31635): ||libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so
11-20 22:54:43.793: E/OpenCV::camera(31635): ||libnative_camera_r4.0.3.so
11-20 22:54:43.793: E/OpenCV::camera(31635): ||libnative_camera_r4.4.0.so
11-20 22:54:43.793: E/OpenCV::camera(31635): ||libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so
11-20 22:54:43.803: E/OpenCV::camera(31635): ||libnative_camera_r4.2.0.so
11-20 22:54:43.803: E/OpenCV::camera(31635): ||libnative_camera_r2.2.0.so
11-20 22:54:43.803: E/OpenCV::camera(31635): ||libnative_camera_r4.0.0.so
11-20 22:54:43.803: E/OpenCV::camera(31635): ||libnative_camera_r4.1.1.so
11-20 22:54:43.803: E/OpenCV::camera(31635): ||libnative_camera_r3.0.1.so
11-20 22:54:43.803: D/OpenCV::camera(31635): try to load library 'libnative_camera_r4.4.0.so'
11-20 22:54:43.803: D/OpenCV::camera(31635): Loaded library '/data/app-lib/org.opencv.engine-1/libnative_camera_r4.4.0.so'
11-20 22:54:43.803: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(31635): CameraHandler::initCameraConnect(0x6009cf5d, 0, 0x611a1ac8, 0x0)
11-20 22:54:43.803: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(31635): Current process name for camera init: ucsc.mitlayan.camera
11-20 22:54:44.033: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(31635): Instantiated new CameraHandler (0x6009cf5d, 0x611a1ac8)
11-20 22:54:44.033: I/OpenCV_NativeCamera(31635): initCameraConnect: [ae-bracket-hdr=Off;ae-bracket-hdr-values=Off,AE-Bracket;antibanding=auto;antibanding-values=off,60hz,50hz,auto;auto-exposure-lock=false;auto-exposure-lock-supported=true;auto-whitebalance-lock=false;auto-whitebalance-lock-supported=true;avtimer=disable;brightness-step=1;camera-mode=0;contrast=5;contrast-step=1;denoise=denoise-off;denoise-values=denoise-off,denoise-on;dis=disable;dis-values=enable,disable;effect=none;effect-values=none,mono,negative,solarize,sepia,posterize,whiteboard,blackboard,aqua,emboss,sketch,neon;exposure-compensation=0;exposure-compensation-step=0.166667;face-detection=off;face-detection-values=off,on;flash-mode=off;flash-mode-values=off,auto,on,torch,red-eye;flip-mode-values=off,flip-v,flip-h,flip-vh;focal-length=2.87;focus-areas=(0,0,0,0,0);focus-distances=Infinity,Infinity,Infinity;focus-mode=auto;focus-mode-values=auto,infinity,macro,continuous-video,continuous-picture;hfr-size-values=;histogram=disable;histogram-values=enable,disable;horizontal-view-angle=65.2;
11-20 22:54:44.033: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(31635): Supported Cameras: (null)
11-20 22:54:44.033: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(31635): Supported Picture Sizes: 3264x2448,3104x2328,3104x1746,2560x1440,1920x1080,1632x1224,864x480,640x480,320x240
11-20 22:54:44.033: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(31635): Supported Picture Formats: jpeg,bayer-mipi-10bggr,bayer-ideal-qcom-10bggr,bayer-qcom-10bggr,yuv422sp
11-20 22:54:44.033: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(31635): Supported Preview Sizes: 1920x1080,1600x1200,1280x720,960x540,640x480,320x240,176x144
11-20 22:54:44.033: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(31635): Supported Preview Formats: yuv420sp,yuv420p,nv12-venus
11-20 22:54:44.033: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(31635): Supported Preview Frame Rates: 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
11-20 22:54:44.033: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(31635): Supported Thumbnail Sizes: 512x288,480x288,256x154,432x288,320x240,176x144,0x0
11-20 22:54:44.033: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(31635): Supported Whitebalance Modes: auto,incandescent,fluorescent,warm-fluorescent,daylight,cloudy-daylight,twilight,shade
11-20 22:54:44.033: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(31635): Supported Effects: none,mono,negative,solarize,sepia,posterize,whiteboard,blackboard,aqua,emboss,sketch,neon
11-20 22:54:44.033: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(31635): Supported Scene Modes: auto,action,portrait,landscape,night,night-portrait,theatre,beach,snow,sunset,steadyphoto,fireworks,sports,party,candlelight,asd,backlight,flowers,AR,hdr,barcode,document,backlight-portrait,sweep-stitch,dark,dish,pet,baby,spot-light,soft-skin,anti-motion-blur,handheld-twilight,high-sensitivity,macro
11-20 22:54:44.033: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(31635): Supported Focus Modes: auto,infinity,macro,continuous-video,continuous-picture
11-20 22:54:44.033: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(31635): Supported Antibanding Options: off,60hz,50hz,auto
11-20 22:54:44.033: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(31635): Supported Flash Modes: off,auto,on,torch,red-eye
11-20 22:54:44.043: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(31635): initCameraConnect: autofocus is set to mode "continuous-video"
11-20 22:54:44.053: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(31635): initCameraConnect: preview format is set to yuv420sp
11-20 22:54:44.063: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(31635): initCameraConnect: preview format is set to 640x480
11-20 22:54:44.063: A/libc(31635): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 31635 (example.camera)
```

Comment: still unable to find the answer. but skip the errors having `javacamera` than `nativecamera`.